# Kee Klamp web shop?

Tags: railing

I have to make a new railling around a stairwell and i would like it to be made of galvanized tubes connected by Kee Klamps.
Does anybody know of any webshops in Europe where i can buy Kee Klamps?

Comment: If you really want a specific brand of item -- [contact the company](http://keesafety.net/contact) and ask them who their resellers/distributors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check these sites out:

http://simplifiedbuilding.de (sells Kee Klamp)

http://simplifiedbuilding.co.uk (only sells aluminum fittings)

Hope that helps!